# Dataflow launcher Payload Java

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I build a stream with an http source and a sink dataflow-launcher to execute a spring batch task named batchPY546Task
To launch this task i set the localFilePath=path-of-the-file parameter.
So in the documentation, with the http source it's possible to pass informations thru the payload.

https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-task-launcher-dataflow/README.adoc

```
{
  "name":"foo",
  "deploymentProps": {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"},
  "args":["--debug", "--foo", "bar"]
}
```

I try many syntaxes :
curl http://localhost:57110 -H"Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"name":"batchPy546Task", "args":{"localFilePath=/tmp/remote-files1/BLM-54.00.01_Multicontrat_Creation_IDCRT011-b.xml"}}'

and all are wrongs

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"name":"batchPy546Task", "args":{"localFilePath=/tmp/remote-files1/BLM-54.00.01_Multicontrat_Creation_IDCRT011-b.xml"}}"; line: 1, column: 34] (through reference chain: org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.task.launcher.dataflow.sink.LaunchRequest["args"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]

How can I pass the parameter lcalFilePath to my task ?

Versions :
 dataflow server 14.2 
 skipper server 2.3.2 
 datafmow auncher is up to date and compatible with dataflow server 2.4.2.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

args must be a json list `"args":["localFilePath=/tmp/..."]`

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved with this syntax :
 curl http://localhost:57110 -H"Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"name":"batchPy546Task", "args":["localFilePath=/tmp/remote-files1/BLM-54.00.01_Multicontrat_Creation_IDCRT011-b.xml"]}'